# Maximum Weight Difference (Code Chef) problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this code, While submitting this code on codechef is showing "wrong answer"

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n,k=map(int,input().split())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    arr.sort()
    arr1=arr[:k]
    arr2=arr[k:]
    print(abs(sum(arr1)-sum(arr2)))
```

Comment: This is of practice easy type

Comment: Could you provide some question context.

Comment: and question is " maximum weight difference"

Comment: a link to the problem is better

Comment: Can you link the question, or write it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your code to this:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
    arr.sort()
    if (k > len(arr) / 2):    //add this line
        k = len(arr) - k      //add this line
    arr1 = arr[:k]
    arr2 = arr[k:]
    print(abs(sum(arr1) - sum(arr2)))
```

Comment: without a proper problem description it is just guessing

Comment: @rioV8 I think I had found the [topic](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXDIFF/) which he practice.